# Passing data between two applications' forms on two different domains

Tags: forms, cross-domain

I have an application with a form that has fields like First Name, Last Name and so on. Also, there is second application I am using that has similar fields. To save time, on my first application I want to create a button to pass some form data of my application to the second application. The problem is that the second application is hosted on the different domain and server and the application does not belong to me. So, in other words, I have no access to the source code or whatever of the second application at all.  I found many JavaScript examples of how to pass data among forms located on the same domain or within same application. But I cannot find any example related to my issue. Also, I tried to use iFrame, but I am facing frame busting. Could anyone advise me on how to achieve my goal or maybe any services or third party tools that can help me?